# Is there a way to know if an user owns a domain?

Tags: django, dns, request, middleware

I'm developing a webapp(Django) that let users have an eshop just with a few clicks. I serve the shops under `https://shopname.mydomain.es` but then I give them the option to use a domain if they want.

For example one of my users (user1) buys "happyuser.com" in a domain provider of his choice. Then I tell them to modify their DNS to point to my server. So far so good, everything works perfectly, I use Nginx to allow access from the connected domains and everything works correctly.

Here comes my doubt. I use a middleware to detect the host, in this case "happyuser.com", I check a table in which I have the relation between user and domain name.

```
class UserDomain(models.Model):
   user = ForeingKey(...)
   domain = UrlField(...)
```

Then I tell Django to serve the correct shop. But what happens if another user (user2) also saves the domain "happyuser.com", how can I know which user shop should I load?. I know is unlikely that this happens, but is there a way to prevent this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need some form of activation process for the domain before you officially associate it with that user account. For example:

- Ask the user to store a particular value (generated randomly for that user) in a DNS `TXT` record, or set a particular random `CNAME` subdomain (e.g. `ijiqjwv87123rbbv8123.happyuser.com`) to point to your domain. Then query that DNS record and see if it's as expected.
- Ask the user to set up the DNS records as necessary to point to your server, then make an HTTP request to that custom domain and a specific path (e.g. `happyuser.com/check`) and expect to receive some specific token from your own server.

Both ways prove that the user has deliberately configured the domain, over which they apparently have control, according to instructions you gave only to them, proving that they must be the owner of the domain for all intents and purposes.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're right, it's a very unlikely issue. There is not much point spending a lot of time on it. Ensure that table with customer domains have unique index on that column, stops the issue form happening and takes few moments to implement.

Comment: Hold my beer while I go and hijack your domains to prevent you from registering them… How much of a problem that will be in practice indeed largely depends on how popular your service will be, but really, this is a relatively easy problem to prevent outright *before* actual users start experiencing it.

Comment: Can you expand on this a bit? I’m not sure how you would want to achieve this... registering thousands of domains within the system? Thats easy to spot and simple captcha would mostly prevent it... limit of domains per account would also solve the issue. Technically dns record is a better option, but it also takes more time and end user expertise to implement. This seems to be new project and as they say in start ups: “don’t optimise too quickly” it is better to gain market share than optimising unused product.